# Once i click on a "div", the href element be added and that link be loaded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend, anchor

Am trying to make a small project where if i click on the wrong div, another webpage loads instantly (for eg here google loads). the HTML and Javascript codes are as follows.

What am I conceptually doing wrong? or even in terms of code, where am I wrong

```js
function get_random_box_id(clicked) {
  var check = document.getElementById(clicked);
  if (check.classList.contains('box_to_select')) {
    check.classList.remove('box_to_select');
    var random_box_number_second = box[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)];
    random_box_number_second.classList.add('box_to_select');
  } else {
    check.onclick = function() {
      this.innerHTML = "<a href ='" + www.google.com + "'> </a>";
    };
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="table1">
  <table class="center">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="box" id="box1" onclick="get_random_box_id(this.id)">1</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="box" id="box2" onclick="get_random_box_id(this.id)">2</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="box" id="box3" onclick="get_random_box_id(this.id)">3</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="box" id="box4" onclick="get_random_box_id(this.id)">4</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="box" id="box5" onclick="get_random_box_id(this.id)">5</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="box" id="box6" onclick="get_random_box_id(this.id)">6</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: what does 'box_to_select' have to do with your desired end result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many things

- do not wrap divs in tds or ths
- do not have inline event handlers but instead delegate as I do below
- have at least one box to select
- do not nest quotes and `www.google.com` is not a variable

  ```
  '<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>';
  ```

will not change immediately - the code below will

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
document.getElementById("table1").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const clicked = e.target;
  if (clicked.classList.contains('box_to_select')) {
    clicked.classList.remove('box_to_select');
    const random_box_number_second = Math.floor(Math.random() * boxes.length);
    console.log(random_box_number_second)
    boxes[random_box_number_second].classList.add('box_to_select');
  } else {
    location = "https://www.google.com"; // change page
  }
});
```

```css
.box_to_select { color:red }
```

```html
<table class="center" id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="box" id="box1">1</th>
      <th class="box box_to_select" id="box2">2</th>
      <th class="box" id="box3">3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="box" id="box4">4</td>
      <td class="box" id="box5">5</td>
      <td class="box" id="box6">6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need an identifier for the right one.
Now you should add an event to all.

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.box')

divs.forEach(div => {
  console.log(div);

  // If the right box
  if (div.classList.contains('box_to_select')) {
    div.addEventListener('click', () => {
      // right stuff
      console.log('right box');
    })


    // If not the right one
  } else {

    div.addEventListener('click', () => {
      // go to google.
      console.log('google');
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<table class="center">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div class="box box_to_select" id="box1" onclick="get_random_box_id(this.id)">1</div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div class="box" id="box2" onclick="get_random_box_id(this.id)">2</div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div class="box" id="box3" onclick="get_random_box_id(this.id)">3</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="box" id="box4" onclick="get_random_box_id(this.id)">4</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="box" id="box5" onclick="get_random_box_id(this.id)">5</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="box" id="box6" onclick="get_random_box_id(this.id)">6</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Your code does not work

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding what you actually want: if you click on "wrong" div, you get redirected to google for this example (based on your submission: "another webpage loads instantly") -> you are just registering new onclick event, not actually firing it.

This code (which is wrong, because `www.google.com` is not a variable, but anyway...) will just register new onclick event:

```
check.onclick = function() {
  this.innerHTML = "<a href ='" + www.google.com + "'> </a>";
};
```

Try something like this:

```
const boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    boxes[i].onclick = (ev) => {
    if (ev.currentTarget.classList.contains('box_to_select')) {
        //do action
    } else {
        window.location.replace("http://google.com");
    }
  };
}
```